# How to save an interactive plot produced by matplot

Tags: matplotlib, graph, export-to-html

I got a super graph that I would like to export as an html file to be showed on an website but I don't know how to figure that. Have you got an idea ?

[image: plot i want to export]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mpld3`. This is a great [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-embed-interactive-python-visualizations-on-your-website-with-python-and-matplotlib/). The `mpld3` library's main functionality is to take an existing `matplotlib` visualization and transform it into some `HTML` code that you can embed on your website.

Use `fig_to_html` file, which accepts a `matplotlib` figure object as its sole argument and returns HTML.

To use the fig_to_html method , simply add the following code to the end of our Python script:

```py
html_str = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
Html_file= open("index.html","w")
Html_file.write(html_str)
Html_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank for the help ! I fiound an antoher way to save it if someone read this post :

import plotly.io as pio
pio.write_html(fig, file="Forecast_HTML.html", auto_open=True)

and it saved it easily !